# Как сделать редирект после регистрации пользователя через соцсети Bitrix?

Tags: битрикс

На странице есть вызов компонента социальные сервисы, пользователь регистрируется только через них http://joxi.ru/a2X45M1SyW1yv2

вызывается вот так

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
"rosacamp:system.auth.form",
"",
Array(
    "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
    "FORGOT_PASSWORD_URL" => "",
    "PROFILE_URL" => "",
    "REGISTER_URL" => "",
    "SHOW_ERRORS" => "N"
)
```

);?>

после этого открывается попап, в котором юзер проходит авторизацию через соц.сети.

в файле init.php добавляю обработчик события

```
AddEventHandler("main", "OnAfterUserAuthorize", Array("AfterRegClass", "OnAfterUserAuthorizeHandler"));
```

в котором делаю редирект

```
Class AfterRegClass{
function OnAfterUserAuthorizeHandler($arFields){
    header("Location:/registration/endreg.php");
}
```

}

но редирект происходит в этом попапе. мне же нужно что бы попап закрылся и прошел редирект

Comment: А что это за компонент такой интересный вы используете?
Это явно не встроенное решение. После авторизации, если ничего не делать, окошко само закрывается?

Answer (score 1):

```
header("Location:/registration/endreg.php");
```

замените на

```
LocalRedirect("/registration/endreg.php")
```

[Документация на метод LocalRedirect](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/functions/other/localredirect.php)

Так же требуется проверить, срабатывает ли событие, обычно делается при помощи логирования, сделать лог можно вот так [AddMessage2Log](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/functions/debug/addmessage2log.php)

Comment: Судя по тексту вопроса, проблему это не решит, хотя и избавит от потенциальных проблем с поддержкой. Окошко-то по прежнему не закрывается.

Answer (score 0):

В init.php

```
AddEventHandler("socialservices", "OnUserLoginSocserv", 'OnUserLoginSocservHandler');

function OnUserLoginSocservHandler($arFields) {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    if(window.opener) {
        window.opener.location = '/personal/'; // ссылка на редирект
    }
    
    window.close();
    </script>
    <?php
    $html = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    
    echo $html;
}
```